# Unable to uninstall a font on Windows (Vista)

Tags: windows, fonts, uninstall

I'm unable to uninstall the font "Helvetica Neue" neither form the Windows Font tool (from the control panel) nor from any font tool downloaded from the internet (for example: The Font Thing 0.8)

Simply because the font "Helvetica Neue" does not appears on the font list of these tools.

Whereas there is "Helvetica Neue" font on the WordPad (for example) font list...

What can I do to remove this font? I cannot even find the TTF/OpenType file...